# При открытии формы выдаёт ошибку

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

Был NET.Framework 4.8. Переписал на NET.Core 5. Там переписывать-то нечего было. 2 класса-то.

При попытке показать форму, у которой я изменил пространство возникает ошибка, не дающая показать форму

> **Индекс за пределами диапазона. Индекс должен быть положительным числом, а его размер не должен превышать размер коллекции. Имя параметра: index**
> в System.Collections.CollectionBase.System.Collections.IList.get_Item(Int32 index) в System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclarationCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
> в Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignerSession.FindDesignableClass(CodeCompileUnit compileUnit)
> в Microsoft.VisualStudio.WinForms.RemoteClient.Loader.RemoteCodeDomDesignerLoader.EnsureDocument(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
> в Microsoft.VisualStudio.WinForms.RemoteClient.Loader.RemoteCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager
> manager)
> в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
> --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
> в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager
> serializationManager)
> в System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)

Сам код, например, MainForm.cs

```
using SFP.Classes;
using SFP.Methods;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace SFP
{
    namespace Forms
    {
        public partial class MainForm : Form
        {
            public MainForm()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainForm.Designer.cs

```
namespace SFP
{
    namespace Forms
    {
        partial class MainForm
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Обязательная переменная конструктора.
            /// </summary>
            private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

            /// <summary>
            /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="disposing">истинно, если управляемый ресурс должен быть удален; иначе ложно.</param>
            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposing && (components != null))
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }

            #region Код, автоматически созданный конструктором форм Windows

            /// <summary>
            /// Требуемый метод для поддержки конструктора — не изменяйте 
            /// содержимое этого метода с помощью редактора кода.
            /// </summary>
            private void InitializeComponent()
            {
                this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
                System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MainForm));
                this.OpenDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
                this.FormContainer = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
                this.SuspendLayout();
                // 
                // OpenDialog
                // 
                this.OpenDialog.FileName = "OpenDialog";
                this.OpenDialog.ReadOnlyChecked = true;
                this.OpenDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
                this.OpenDialog.ShowReadOnly = true;
                this.OpenDialog.SupportMultiDottedExtensions = true;
                // 
                // FormContainer
                // 
                resources.ApplyResources(this.FormContainer, "FormContainer");
                this.FormContainer.Name = "FormContainer";
                // 
                // MainForm
                // 
                resources.ApplyResources(this, "$this");
                this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
                this.Controls.Add(this.FormContainer);
                this.KeyPreview = true;
                this.Name = "MainForm";
                this.ResumeLayout(false);

            }

            #endregion
            private System.Windows.Forms.ImageList MenuImagesSmall;
            private System.Windows.Forms.ImageList MenuImagesLarge;
            public System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog OpenDialog;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Panel FormContainer;
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using SFP.Forms;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace SFP
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Скриншот окна:]

Приложение запускается и ведёт себя как до ошибки.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127614/discussion-on-question-by-alexander-----).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, вместо

```cs
namespace SFP
{
    namespace Forms
    {
    }
}
```

надо сделать вот так

```cs
namespace SFP.Forms
{
}
```

Если не прокатит, закройте студию. Удалите папки bin и obj в каталоге с проектом и запустите студию заново.

Comment: ВЫ -- ГЕНИЙ! Спасибо.

Comment: Хм, это просто краткая форма записи. Оба способа должны работать.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я дописал ответ, думаю помогло как раз последнее.

Comment: @aepot, вы сильно удивитесь, но помогло как раз сокращение namespace'ов.